# How to stop Mission Control from rearranging screens?

Tags: macos, desktop, spaces, mission-control

If I have arranged Finder to the left of the desktop and Slack to the right, and have Sketch further to the right, there's a reason for that. It's an organization strategy to make my work easier and keep track of the many windows I have open. **BUT**, macOS rearranges them if I click on the application icon from the Dock and rather than swiping over to the screen in the specified order, it moves it next the Desktop.

**Is there a way to stop that from happening? A way to pin screens to the desired position?**

Comment: I am really interested on how to keep the position of windows when viewing the mission control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** -> **Mission Control** and uncheck: *Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use*.